# VS Code Extension w/ Webview to Connect to API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create a VS Code extension that will connect to an API and display some data.

The API I want to connect to uses [Auth0](https://auth0.com) authentication. Once authenticated, I will display data for the user.

Is this something I can do with Webviews in VS Code or do I need to use another approach?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can do that.

---

From the [docs](https://vscode-ppe.azurewebsites.net/docs/extensionAPI/patterns-and-principles#_extension-manifest):

> As the `extension host` is a Node.js process, you can use the Node API in your extensions and even better you can reuse existing Node.js modules when implementing an extension. You define your module dependencies inside the `package.json` and you use npm to install a Node.js module.

With this in mind you can use the [`node-auth0`](https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0) (or some other) package to handle authentication. So your extension could do the following steps:

1. Ask the user for credentials (username and password) with the [`vscode.window.showInputBox`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showInputBox) API. This could also be done with a webview, however the `showInputBox` API is more straight forward and easier to start with.
2. Use the `node-auth0` package to handle authentication
3. Retrieve data from your API
4. Show the data to the user using a webview

To get started with webviews you can check out the [webview extension sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webview-sample).

Comment: I tried this, but found out that login with Social Identity Providers cannot be done through API, it has to browser based. (https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#social)